# (deck.gl) custom basemap with globe-ui using blue marble

Tags: deck.gl

I would like to use the [blue marble image](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/74218/december-blue-marble-next-generation/74220l) from Nasa as a basemap on the globe view. Most other WebGL mapping frameworks let you do this.
Appreciate some help, pure typescript if possible (thats why i want to work with deck.gl)

Answer (score 0):

way to do this with deck.gl is to create a globeview:

```
this.deckgl = new Deck({
        initialViewState: INITIAL_VIEW_STATE,
        views: new GlobeView({id: 'globe', controller: true})....
```

create the BitmapLayer:

```
createWorldLayer() {
    return new BitmapLayer({
      id: 'WORLD_MAP',
      bounds: [-180, -90, 180, 90],
      image: WORLD_MAP //this is a image url (local or remote)
    })
  }
```

and add it to the view:

```
this.deckgl.props.layers.push(myWorldLayer)
```